# asp.net ValidationSummary location/focus

Tags: asp.net, focus, location, validationsummary

I am using asp.net ValidationSummary. my form is 1.5 of the screen which means user can not see the complete form at a time and s/he has to scroll. The ValidationSummary is located at the bottom of the page. User is at the top of the page and error occurs then s/he won't be able to see the ValidationSummary because neither this control gets focus nor it makes the browser scroll down to show itself. The case is same if user is at the bottom of the page and ValidationSummary is at the top.

Please suggest how to show this ValidationSummary automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

I find the validation summary isn't the most user friendly for long forms especially when scrolling appears.

Why not remove the validation summary and highlight the fields with the errors with a validation errror message beside the control and a visual idicator beside the submit button? This appraoch would be a lot mroe user friendly

Comment: The form has good number of fields which are side by side (2 columns) so there isn't enough space to show error message

Comment: Why not put the label above the control and pu tthe error message beside the label?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you move the `ValidationSummary` to the top then?

Or just [style the ValidationSummary](http://weblogs.asp.net/samirgeorge/archive/2009/05/26/styling-the-validationsummary-control-using-css-only.aspx).

This is a UI problem, not a technical one.

Comment: The problem is again the same as i mentioned if it is placed at the top. Styling is not the issue but showing/focusing the error message.